# SQL Multiple questions to find most relevant data

Tags: sql, database, database-design, relational-database

I want to build a fairly simple application that will rely heavily on the ability to query data through several tables and return the most relevant information.

I recently did a brief course in relational databases however, what I hope to achieve was below the scope of what we covered. I'm a bit lost on where to start with this and looking for some general information on how I should approach the functionality and querying of the data. Obviously, I'm not looking for someone to reply with a lot of code but more a point in the right direction.

What I would like to do:

1. I would like for a group of test users to pick their top 5 interests or pastimes.
2. I would then like them to answer 10 simple questions about their personality.
3. I would like a new end user to answer the same 10 questions as the test users.
4. I would like to return the most relevant interests or pastimes in descending order to the end user based on how closely their answers matched answers given by the test group, ie, if they have a similar personality they might enjoy the same interests or pastimes.

I suppose this is probably very like how a dating website might work.

From what I learnt on the course I think I will require the following tables however there may be a better way:

```
User (UserID, Fname, Lname, Age)
Question (QuestionID, Question, Answer1, Answer2, Answer3, Answer4, Answer5)...user would pick 1 answer here only
User/Question (UserID/QuestionID, AnswerGiven)
Pastime (PastimeID, PastimeName, Description)
User/Pastime (UserID/PastimeID)
```

I should add that the answers to the questions are multiple choice and are not text entered by the user, therefore numbers only are required, ie. user has selected answer number 4.

Can anyone point me in the right direction for a) handling the questions/answers, b) How can I group all the answers together to query the database in one go instead of multiple times, c) How can I query the database to return the most relevant pastimes based on how similarly the end user answered the questions to the test users.

Any help at all is much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I would turn the Answers into their own small table: Answer Table: AnswerID, AnswerText. Then User/Question would contain UserID, QuestionID, AnswerID.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion dcoli. Also, I just edited my original question to say that the questions are multiple choice and so, answers will be numbers only (No answerText)

Comment: Do you mean the value of the answer will be a number (like solving math problems) or there will be an id number assigned to each multiple choice option, and a textual answer beside the checkbox? If the latter, my table would still be helpful.

Comment: Hi, it's the latter, a number assigned to each option. For example, the question might be: what is you favourite animal? The user clicks the corresponding button: 1. Dog, 2. Cat, 3. Horse etc. What I can't figure out is the best way to bring all the user's answers together, run a new user's answers against all the existing test users answers to find out who they're most like, but then return the the most relevant test users pastimes. It also needs to be the "most like" as they might not answer every question exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to my comments, I think you should handle comparing users' answers in code. It is probably possible to do it in SQL, using something like the MIN function, but I'm not sure it would be any faster, and might be slower, than in code. Create an array of users, where every array element is a user object, containing keys of question id and values of answer id. Then iterate through one object and the next object, summing the number of matches, and save the user that has the highest number of matches. Then go to the next user, and do the same thing, only saving him if he has more matches. If someone matches perfectly you might just want to break the loop and return the user. If you want it to be more random than just the first one to match, mix up the users in the array randomly beforehand.